# Mountain Lion Crashing while hibernating

Tags: macos, crash

I had one crash yesterday and one tomorrow on my iMac running mountain lion while the computer was hibernating. In both cases the computer restarted alone.

The messa is always the same: **mountain lion your computer restarted because of a problem**

In both cases I had an iPhone 4S attached on the USB port.

This are today's crash log.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  172087 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    

Sun Sep 23 00:26:36 2012
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8020ab7bd5): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa208e032, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000002334d000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff7fa208e026, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff81813c3eb0, RBP: 0xffffff81813c3ec0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff803b72a000
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0xffffff81732cfbc0, R10: 0x000000000568b1cf, R11: 0x0000000000000001
R12: 0x0000000000560f93, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7fa208e032, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81813c3b50 : 0xffffff8020a1d626 
0xffffff81813c3bc0 : 0xffffff8020ab7bd5 
0xffffff81813c3d90 : 0xffffff8020ace4ed 
0xffffff81813c3db0 : 0xffffff7fa208e032 
0xffffff81813c3ec0 : 0xffffff7fa27a1cea 
0xffffff81813c3ef0 : 0xffffff8020e472a8 
0xffffff81813c3f30 : 0xffffff8020e45daa 
0xffffff81813c3f80 : 0xffffff8020e45ed9 
0xffffff81813c3fb0 : 0xffffff8020ab26b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator(1.0)[D89E4100-9C89-3C99-B34B-F7790E1A0B8B]@0xffffff7fa279b000->0xffffff7fa2b68fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily(19.0.26)[409C5206-05B3-301D-995E-5B269A4EEF5E]@0xffffff7fa2749000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.1)[9901C237-547C-3B52-99DE-C4870A19E2B5]@0xffffff7fa1050000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.5)[86DDB71C-A73A-3EBE-AC44-0BC9A38B9A44]@0xffffff7fa15b5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.5)[803496D0-ADAD-3ADB-B071-8A0A197DA53D]@0xffffff7fa1572000
         com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer(8.0)[4CD59A3C-4442-36CB-8026-2095FE6B032A]@0xffffff7fa2086000->0xffffff7fa2098fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7fa14e1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.1)[9901C237-547C-3B52-99DE-C4870A19E2B5]@0xffffff7fa1050000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(8.0.0)[7B2EC6D1-101A-3928-919E-337D6724752A]@0xffffff7fa1e9c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.5)[803496D0-ADAD-3ADB-B071-8A0A197DA53D]@0xffffff7fa1572000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12C54

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 
Kernel slide:     0x0000000020800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8020a00000
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 29876329699063
last loaded kext at 23524168880798: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7fa2d01000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 23588528509160: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7fa2d01000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelProfile  97
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   75.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.1.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  600.70.23
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    97
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  97
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  165.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   165.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  235.28
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
System Profile:
Model: iMac12,2, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 1.72f1
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424655302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344243313333392E4D313646
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424655302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344243313333392E4D313646
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.70.23-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0409  (NEC Corporation), 0x005a, 0xfa130000 / 5
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0409  (NEC Corporation), 0x005a, 0xfa134000 / 8
USB Device: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge, 0x152d  (JMicron Technology Corp.), 0x2329, 0xfa131000 / 7
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x050d  (Belkin Corporation), 0x0307, 0xfd140000 / 5
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

I am verifying all stuff that is running in the background and for that matter, I have used the app Consultan's Canary, that gives me a full report of everything installed as services, daemons, etc. This is the report:

If you guys think something in this list is useless, please let me know. I love to trim unnecessary stuff from my mac.

```
                                 Login Items                                   

/Volumes/GigaSuper/applications/BetterTouchTool.app
/Applications/Typinator.app

                                      ---                                       

                          Overly Privileged Processes                           


                                      ---                                       

                         Foreign System Augmentations


                               Automator Actions                                

/System/Library/Automator
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Create Annotated Movie File.action            com.Apple.QuickTime.Automator.Create_Annotated_Movie_File

/Library/Automator
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Save as Adobe PDF.action                      com.adobe.Automator.Save as Adobe PDF

                                   Frameworks                                   

/Library/Frameworks
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Adlm.framework                                Adlm.framework
   Adobe AIR.framework                           com.adobe.AIR
   EWSMac.framework                              com.eSellerate.EWSMac67108866
   HPDeviceModel.framework                       com.hp.dmf
   HPPml.framework                               com.hp.hpio.HPPmlFramework
   HPServicesInterface.framework                 com.hp.hpio.HPServicesInterfaceFramework
   HPSmartPrint.framework                        com.hp.print.HPSmartPrint
   ONCore.framework                              com.ononesoftware.ONCore
   ONDocument.framework                          com.ononesoftware.ONDocument
   onOneToolbox.framework                        com.ononesoftware.onOneToolbox
   ONProxySupport.framework                      com.yourcompany.ONProxySupport
   ONPSEmulator.framework                        com.ononesoftware.ONPSEmulator
   PFAssistive.framework                         com.pfiddlesoft.PFAssistive
   PFEventTaps.framework                         com.pfiddlesoft.PFEventTaps
   TIAppKit.framework                            com.ti.eps.TIConnectX.TIAppKit
   TIConnectManagerXInteraction.framework        com.ti.eps.TIConnectX.Connect Manager X interaction
   TIDataConversionBase.framework                com.ti.eps.TIConnectX.TIDataConversionBase
   TIPluginLocator.framework                     com.ti.eps.ticonnectX.TIPluginLocator
   TSLicense.framework                           net.telestream.license
   WacomMultiTouch.framework                     com.wacom.WacomMultiTouch
   XUL.framework                                 org.mozilla.xulrunner

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   GPUSupport.framework                          ?

                                 Input Managers                                 

/Library/InputManagers
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Safari AdBlock                                net.sourceforge.SafariAdBlockLoader

                            Internet/Safari Plug-Ins                            

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   DivXBrowserPlugin.plugin                      com.divx.DivXBrowserPlugin
   Flash Player.plugin                           com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin
   OVSHelper.plugin                              com.divx.OVSHelper

                               Kernel Extensions                                

/System/Library/Extensions
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Accusys6xxxx.kext                             com.Accusys.driver.Acxxx
   BJUSBLoad.kext                                jp.co.canon.bj.print.BJUSBLoad
   BoomDevice.kext                               com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice
   CalDigitHDProDrv.kext                         com.CalDigit.driver.HDPro
   EPSONUSBPrintClass.kext                       com.epson.print.kext.USBPrintClass
   HighPointIOP.kext                             com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointIOP
   HighPointRR.kext                              com.highpoint-tech.kext.HighPointRR
   hp_designjet_series.kext                      com.hp.print.hpio.Designjet.kext
   hp_Deskjet_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Deskjet.kext
   hp_fax_io.kext                                com.hp.kext.hp-fax-io
   hp_Inkjet1_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet1.kext
   hp_Inkjet2_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet2.kext
   hp_Inkjet3_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet3.kext
   hp_Inkjet4_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet4.kext
   hp_Inkjet5_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet5.kext
   hp_Inkjet7_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.inkjet7.kext
   hp_Inkjet8_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.inkjet8.kext
   hp_Inkjet9_io_enabler.kext                    com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet9.kext
   hp_Inkjet_io_enabler.kext                     com.hp.print.hpio.Inkjet.kext
   hp_io_printerclassdriver_enabler.kext         com.hp.hpio.hp_io_printerclassdriver_enabler
   hp_Laserjet_io_enabler.kext                   com.hp.print.hpio.Laserjet.kext
   hp_Officejet_io_enabler.kext                  com.hp.print.hpio.Officejet.kext
   hp_Photosmart_io_enabler.kext                 com.hp.print.hpio.Photosmart.kext
   hp_PhotosmartPro_io_enabler.kext              com.hp.print.hpio.PhotosmartPro.kext
   hp_psa640_io_enabler.kext                     com.hp.hpio.hp_psa640_io_enabler
   hp_qc_io_enabler.kext                         com.hp.hpio.hp_psa530_630_io_enabler
   LogitechHIDDevices.kext                       com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver
   Pen Tablet.kext                               com.wacom.kext.pentablet
   PromiseSTEX.kext                              com.promise.driver.stex
   TabletDriverCFPlugin.bundle                   Wacom Tablet 5.2.5-3

                                  Launchd Jobs                                  

/Library/LaunchAgents
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist               com.adobe.AAM.Startup-1.0
   com.adobe.CS4ServiceManager.plist             com.adobe.CS4ServiceManager
   com.adobe.CS5ServiceManager.plist             com.adobe.CS5ServiceManager
   com.wacom.pentablet.plist                     com.wacom.pentablet

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   org.freeradius.radiusd.plist                  org.freeradius.radiusd
   org.openldap.slapd.plist                      org.openldap.slapd
   org.postgresql.postgres_alt.plist             org.postgresql.postgres_alt

/Library/LaunchDaemons
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   com.adobe.fpsaud.plist                        com.adobe.fpsaud

                                  MIDI Drivers                                  

/Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   MAudioFireWireMIDI.plugin                     com.m-audio.midiplug.fw410

                          System Preferences Plug-Ins                           

/Library/PreferencePanes
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Flash Player.prefPane                         com.adobe.flashplayerpreferences
   PenTablet.prefPane                            com.wacom.PenTabletSettingsPrefPane

/Users/fireball/Library/PreferencePanes
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   AirPrintActivator.prefPane                    com.netputing.AirPrintActivator
   BTTPrefs.prefPane                             com.hegenberg.bttprefs
   Perian.prefPane                               org.perian.PerianPane

                               QuickTime Plug-Ins                               

/Library/QuickTime
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   DivX Decoder.component                        com.DivXInc.DivXDecoder
   FLV.component                                 com.macromedia.FLVExporter
   MayaIFF.component                             com.yourcompany.MayaIFF
   SoundboothScoreCodec.component                com.adobe.SoundboothScoreAudioCodec
   TSCC.component                                com.techsmith.TSCCComponentBundle

/Users/fireball/Library/QuickTime
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   AC3MovieImport.component                      com.cod3r.ac3movieimport
   Perian.component                              org.perian.Perian
   Save as AVI.component                         com.squared5.SaveAsAVI

                               Safari Extensions                                

/Users/fireball/Library/Safari/Extensions
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   AdBlock-1.safariextz                          com.betafish.adblockforsafari
   Extensions.plist                              Extensions.plist



                              Scripting Additions                               

/Library/ScriptingAdditions
 FS Name:                                      Bundle ID:
   Adobe Unit Types.osax                         ascr
```

As I final note I must say that I have reseted the PRAM, booted in console mode and give it a /fsck -fy and run Disk Utility repair permissions (found nothing wrong)

---

NOTE: just after the crash, I rebooted and found this on the system log:

```
Sep 24 01:59:22 iMac.local coreaudiod[122]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "`2�
    ����P2�
    ����".
```

I also see these other messages from previous restarts:

```
Sep 23 16:01:36 imac.home coreaudiod[128]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "`2<-????P2<-?????9?E????".
Sep 24 00:33:55 imac.home coreaudiod[126]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "`2?????P2????????'?????\?'?????<?m????Wcd
                                 ????".
Sep 24 01:59:22 iMac.local coreaudiod[122]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "`2?
Sep 24 02:36:36 imac.home coreaudiod[126]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "`?\0????P?\0????".
```

where is that string and how do I fix it?

I appreciate your help.  Thanks

Comment: This appears to be related to your Graphics Card.

Comment: what, the crash or the strings? The strings say coreaudio...

Comment: The crash, I mean. I have no idea of the coreaudiod problem, though many people seem to have it.

Comment: I get exactly the same crash on my macbook pro whilst it's sleeping, pretty certain it started after upgrading to mountain lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution: just turned off WAKE FOR NETWORK ACCESS on the energy saver panel. No more crashes.