# computer sleeps, then crashes later

Tags: macos, crash, mac-pro

For the past several weeks, this has been happening.

I put the computer to sleep at night, and when I wake the computer up the next morning, my computer has restarted itself.

There's a "Problem Report for OSX" dialog box on the screen, letting me send some notes off to Apple. That's it.

Today, I was working on another computer as the one in question fell asleep. Then about an hour later, it restarted itself and told me about an unexpected problem.

I have no idea what's happening or why it's doing this. I haven't really installed anything interesting lately (Sublime Text 2, git...)

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 on a Mac Pro. I've got the OS installed on a 120GB Mercury EXTREME Pro 6G SSD.

Here's the crash report:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  13858 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    FC8C0D5B-AD9E-CAF0-B2F3-0DB6DAD11742

Thu Nov  1 15:57:21 2012
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801d8b7bd5): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9ee44032, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000001fffe000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0xffffff7f9ee44026, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff80d493beb0, RBP: 0xffffff80d493bec0, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff802e21c800
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0xffffff80c8d10b98, R10: 0x000000000163b4c7, R11: 0x00000000ffffff80
R12: 0x00000000001fa3c2, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff7f9ee44032, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80d493bb50 : 0xffffff801d81d626 
0xffffff80d493bbc0 : 0xffffff801d8b7bd5 
0xffffff80d493bd90 : 0xffffff801d8ce4ed 
0xffffff80d493bdb0 : 0xffffff7f9ee44032 
0xffffff80d493bec0 : 0xffffff7f9f44dcea 
0xffffff80d493bef0 : 0xffffff801dc472a8 
0xffffff80d493bf30 : 0xffffff801dc45daa 
0xffffff80d493bf80 : 0xffffff801dc45ed9 
0xffffff80d493bfb0 : 0xffffff801d8b26b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator(1.0)[D89E4100-9C89-3C99-B34B-F7790E1A0B8B]@0xffffff7f9f447000->0xffffff7f9f814fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily(19.0.26)[7DC411F1-A646-3A4A-B160-A1492F5EC0ED]@0xffffff7f9f3f5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.2)[B1B77B26-7984-302F-BA8E-544DD3D75E73]@0xffffff7f9de50000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.5)[86DDB71C-A73A-3EBE-AC44-0BC9A38B9A44]@0xffffff7f9e384000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.5)[803496D0-ADAD-3ADB-B071-8A0A197DA53D]@0xffffff7f9e341000
         com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer(8.0)[4CD59A3C-4442-36CB-8026-2095FE6B032A]@0xffffff7f9ee3c000->0xffffff7f9ee4efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f9e2dc000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.2)[B1B77B26-7984-302F-BA8E-544DD3D75E73]@0xffffff7f9de50000
            dependency: com.apple.kext.AMDSupport(8.0.0)[7B2EC6D1-101A-3928-919E-337D6724752A]@0xffffff7f9ec52000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.5)[803496D0-ADAD-3ADB-B071-8A0A197DA53D]@0xffffff7f9e341000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x000000001d600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801d800000
System model name: MacPro3,1 (Mac-F42C88C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 15783059910952
last loaded kext at 15683132552265: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f9f94a000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 10827864706917: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f9f947000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   75.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver 1.1.9
com.apple.iokit.CSRBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport   4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntel8254XEthernet    3.1.1b1
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   600.36.17
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  235.28
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.kext.AMD5000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    165.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   165.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacPro3,1, BootROM MP31.006C.B05, 8 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz, 6 GB, SMC 1.25f4
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5770, ATI Radeon HD 5770, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 1, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 800 MHz, 0x05F7, 0x000000003732353642363145353830304600
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 2, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 800 MHz, 0x05F7, 0x000000003732353642363145353830304600
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 1, 1 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 800 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x48594D5035313241373243503844332D5335
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 2, 1 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 800 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x48594D5035313241373243503844332D5335
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Harmony 900, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en2
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 5770, sppci_displaycontroller, Slot-1
PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 5770, ATY,HoolockParent, Slot-1
PCI Card: pci1033,35, sppci_usbopenhost, Slot-3@7,0,0
PCI Card: pci1033,35, sppci_usbopenhost, Slot-3@7,0,1
PCI Card: pci1033,e0, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Slot-3@7,0,2
Serial ATA Device: ST3500320AS, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0, 3 TB
Serial ATA Device: OWC Mercury EXTREME Pro 6G SSD, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD10EACS-00ZJB0, 1 TB
Parallel ATA Device: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-112D
Parallel ATA Device: _NEC DVD_RW ND-2500A
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2504, 0xfd400000 / 3
USB Device: DSP55 Adapter, 0x047f  (Plantronics, Inc.), 0xd055, 0xfd420000 / 6
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd410000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x0220, 0xfd412000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2502, 0xfd300000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2602, 0xfd310000 / 4
USB Device: Flash Card Reader, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2228, 0xfd311000 / 7
USB Device: MX860 series, 0x04a9  (Canon Inc.), 0x1735, 0x40100000 / 2
USB Device: Bose USB Audio, 0x05a7  (Bose Corporation), 0x1020, 0x00200000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8206, 0x5d200000 / 2
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, 800mbit_speed
```

Comment: "com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator" - looks like the same problem I'm having

Comment: Do you have any devices attached to the Mac at the time? Does it do the same thing in a newly created user account?

Comment: I have a 3TB hard disk that is sometimes connected. I haven't been able to correlate the crashes with it being connected or not, and I have not tried the new user account.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65098/mountain-lion-crashing-while-hibernating - both crashes are in the same com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator(1.0)[D89E4100-9C89-3C99-B34B-F7790E1A0B8B] kernel extension and both occur when sleeping.